# Editing Accent Shortcuts (overring)

Tags: keyboard

I've been doing some linguistics work for a side project, and I'm having trouble typing some characters efficiently, namely those with overrings on them.

For most accent types, like the acute (<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and umlaut (<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), I can simply type in the combination and get the desired symbol. However, this same process does not work with overrings. I can type the overring A, "å", with the <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut. However, I cannot do the same with overring E, "e̊", and overring O, "o̊".

Weirdly, these are also not available by holding down the letters and selecting them from the alternate forms menu (for instance by holding down the letter E). Is there any way to get these letters more efficiently? Right now I am simply copy-pasting them, but this is somewhat slow.

Thank you in advance. I have some day-to-day computer skills, but nothing too technical for reference. I hope everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the [ABC extended input source](https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/). It makes more overring characters via option k, then the base.  e̊ o̊

Some more info about ABC Extended can be found [here](https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2021/05/macos-abc-extended-keyboard-further.html) and [here](https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2016/07/os-x-abc-extended-keyboard-layout.html).